# The UTC time represented when the offset is applied must be between year 0 and 10,000. Parameter name: offset

Tags: asp.net-mvc, exception, datetimeoffset

I have the following code in an ASP.NET MVC3 Controller:

```
public PartialViewResult GetCalendar(int? month, int? year)
    {
        var test = new DateTime((year.HasValue ? year.Value : 1), (month.HasValue ? month.Value : 1), 1);
        return PartialView("Calendar", new DateTimeOffset(test));
    }
```

My view model is `DateTimeOffset?`

What is the reason for the exception thrown?

Comment: Well what's the value of `month` and `year` in the case when it fails? (Note that the null-coalescing operator would make this simpler, btw.)

Comment: 1 and 1, so that it's like DateTime.MinValue

Comment: @JonSkeet thanks for reminding about null-coalescing operator

Answer (score 67, accepted):

The `DateTimeOffset` constructor first converts any `DateTime` that is not of `Kind` 'UTC' to the equivalent UTC time. It will then check whether the UTC-equivalent `DateTime` falls outside of the bounds of `DateTimeOffset.MinValue` and `DateTimeOffset.MaxValue`, and if it does, will throw an `ArgumentOutOfRangeException` similar to the one you are experiencing.

Check the `DateTime.Kind` of the variable `test` that you are using, and if it is not 'UTC', work out if a conversion to UTC will make the `DateTime` specified by `test` fall outside of those bounds - according to the MSDN documentation, the `MinValue` and `MaxValue` (in UTC) are '1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM +00:00' and '12/31/9999 11:59:59 PM +00:00' respectively.

The docs ([DateTimeOffset.MinValue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetimeoffset.minvalue.aspx)) note that:

"Any DateTimeOffset value is converted to Coordinated Universal Time (UTC) before the method performs the comparison with MinValue. This means that a DateTimeOffset value whose date and time are close to the minimum range, but whose offset is positive, may throw an exception. For example, the value 1/1/0001 1:00:00 AM +02:00 is out of range because it is one hour earlier than MinValue when it is converted to UTC."

And also ([DateTimeOffset.MaxValue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetimeoffset.maxvalue.aspx)):

"Any DateTimeOffset value is converted to Coordinated Universal Time (UTC) before the method compares it with MaxValue. This means that a DateTimeOffset value whose date and time are close to the maximum range, but whose offset is negative, may throw an exception. For example, the value 12/31/9999 11:00 PM -02:00 is out of range because it is one hour later than MaxValue when it is converted to UTC."

And as per the docs ([DateTimeOffset Constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb337819.aspx)), the offset that is applied to a non-UTC `Kind` is the "offset of the local system's current time zone".

Comment: I don't know why it's not working, finally I solved it by changing the model to DateTime?

Comment: Like chamila said, it fails because the date is outside the range allowed. `new DateTimeOffset(DateTime.MinValue)` will fail on any computer with a timezone that is ahead of UTC (positive offset), and `new DateTimeOffset(DateTime.MaxValue)` will fail on any computer with a timezone that is behind UTC (negative offset).

Comment: Part of the problem is MinValue/MaxValue have DateTimeKind = unspecified. If you convert them to UTC, it works. 

<!-- language: c# -->
    var x1 = new DateTimeOffset(DateTime.MaxValue.ToUniversalTime());
    var x2 = new DateTimeOffset(DateTime.MinValue.ToUniversalTime());

Answer (score 19):

I just had this issue, introduced by the part of my team that's on a negative UTC zone...

What chamila_c posted is the real reason why this happens, but I needed a quick fix.

To "solve it" I basically created this extension:

```
public static class DateTimeExtensions
{
    public static DateTimeOffset ToDateTimeOffset(this DateTime dateTime)
    {
        return dateTime.ToUniversalTime() <= DateTimeOffset.MinValue.UtcDateTime
                   ? DateTimeOffset.MinValue 
                   : new DateTimeOffset(dateTime);
    }
}
```

you might also want to check against the MaxValue.

Answer (score 5):

If the data type you are dealing with is a DateTime, you should create a DateTime object specifying the Kind.

```
DateTime maxDate = DateTime.SpecifyKind(DateTime.MaxValue, DateTimeKind.UTC);
```

When this converts to the DateTimeOffset data type, you will not get that error.

Answer (score 2):

This can happen during Azure Function development when you set a timer trigger schedule in function.json so it never runs, like this:

```json
{
  "scriptFile": "__init__.py",
  "bindings": [
    {
        "name": "mytimer",
        "type": "timerTrigger",
        "direction": "in",
        "schedule": "0 0 0 31 2 *"
    }
  ]
}
```

... where I have set this to run on February 31st (that is, never.)  Apparently "never" is outside the allowable date range.  Solution is to be less tricky and just set a real date in the far future:

```json
{
  "scriptFile": "__init__.py",
  "bindings": [
    {
        "name": "mytimer",
        "type": "timerTrigger",
        "direction": "in",
        "schedule": "0 0 0 1 1 * "
    }
  ]
}
```

(Run once on January 1st, won't run until next year.)

Again, credit to Chamila Chulatunga for describing the root of the problem.